# What can we say about, $b=\langle x^TA,x \rangle$?

Tags: matrices, inner-products, matrix-rank

I wish to comment if the quantity, defined by,
\begin{equation}
b=\langle x^T A,x \rangle
\end{equation}
is either positive or negative? Here in this expression $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a rank deficient matrix. I want to know if $b \geq 0$? Please help me prove it! Thanks for your time!

Comment: What does $\langle x^T,A\rangle$ mean?

Comment: $\langle,\rangle$ defines the inner product.

Comment: What's the "inner product" of a vector with a matrix? As far as I know, inner products are symmetric/Hermitian bilinear/sesquilinear maps on a real/complex vector space.

Comment: Do you mean $x^TAx$?

Comment: actually I wanted to write $x^TA$. So I chose, $\langle x,A\rangle$.

Comment: You're rediscovering positive semidefiniteness.

Comment: But even in PSD case, can't we write, $0\leq x^TAx \leq \lambda_{max}(A) \|x\|^2$?

Comment: That is true by definition of positive semidefiniteness

Answer (score 0):

No reason for $x^TAx$ to be positive. Consider 
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}, x = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

Then $x^TAx = -1$.

Comment: So we can't comment on the sign of x^TAx if A is rank deficient? I know for PD matrices, this term is lower bounded by $\lambda_{min}(A) \|x\|^2$ which is positive number

Comment: Nor even if $A$ is full rank, consider $A = \operatorname{diag}(1, -1)$.

Comment: Is it possible to find a bound over $x^TAx$ when A is rank deficient?